# Angular ui-select : dropdown larger than select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have such an issue. When I click on ui-select the dropdown appears normal. But if I will resize the window the dropdown became larger than ui-select and sometimes ui-select pushes other inputs to the left.
Who faced with this problem? Any solution?

### **Updated**

I found the solution. I have to apply css 'width: 100% !important' to input with class .ui-select-search and thats all. Sorry, it's hard to recreate the problem in plunker.

Comment: Put the dropdown width in `pixel` size instead of % size

Comment: I need adaptivity

Comment: Can you show me you css class or style which is apply on your field?

Comment: Any select styles. I only wrapped select in a div and gave it width in %

Comment: give it to pixel, don't give % for over all resolution

Comment: I need select adaptive

Comment: put your code here or create plunker or fiddle for better solution.